Meaning of Regularization
In renormalization theory, we choose a certain type of regularization method in order to study the analytic behavior of UV divergence (whether it diverges as $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} 1/\epsilon$, $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\ln(1/\epsilon)$, or $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} 1/\epsilon^2$.
As for as I learnt, the results after regularizations are different from others computed in different regularizations, and I wonder then if it is worth studying the analytic behavior of UV divergence? Or, is it even important to study it? Because the infinite parameters introduced in regularizations should vanish in renormalization process when we try to calculated the observable.

Regularisation pulls back various integral quantities from actually running off to infinity, so that we can arrange for those offending parts to cancel between different integral quantities, in the thing we call renormalisation. After that, all the remaining quantities no longer have a difficulty with infinity, and so we can let the regulator go back to the unregulated limit, the physical limits. Yes, the regularisation can change results, but we hope that the physical limits are unique and independent of choice of regularisation.
